# My Internet connection is not working after changing the driver from Nvidia 515 to Nouveau

Tags: drivers, wireless

I have tried several things in different posts but nothing works. I would also see as a solution establishing factory settings or some type of clean. Im not capable of opening GRUB menu in any way.
I need someone who understands well ubuntu and guides me on solving this problem.
Im running Ubuntu 22.04

Thank you very much, its my first post.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask a must read.

Comment: Im using ubuntu 22.04, the latest version